# How to i make my print command stop print whats after a semi-colon?

Tags: c#

```
namespace TextEditor
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void code()
    {
        String input = TB.Text;

        if (input.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("print: "))
        {
            String print = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
            MessageBox.Show(print, "Console");
        }
    }

    //When about is clicked
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Personal stuff", "IDK");
    }

    //Reset text when new is clicked
    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TB.Text = "";
    }

    private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        code();
    }
}
}
```

> How do I make it to were it only reads whats between "print: " and the semi-colon? Like if I typed (in the text box (TB)) "print: Hello World;" and on the next line I typed "Ignore this" it will come on the message box saying only "Hello World".

Comment: This question has way to many possible answers. Please be more specific.

Comment: Learn how to use IndexOf and Substring methods of string. You can also use RegEx which is a bit more of a learning curve IMO.

Comment: Mark answered my question i don't need anymore help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
 String input = TB.Text;
       if (input.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print: "))
        {
            String print = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);

            MessageBox.Show(print.Split(';')[0], "Console");
        }
```

Comment: or may be `input.IndexOf(':')+1` if incase user forgets to keep any whitespaces.

Comment: His code already checks if there is a space: `input.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print: "))`

Comment: Thanks mark and Niraj. I see how that works.

Comment: Yes, but I would rather recommend Trimming Start, if in case user leaves more spaces (if they are unintended to print).